# HTML vs response.url - How to grab the price with xpath

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

This is what I see in the html from my browser

```
   <li class="lvprice prc">

            <span  class="bold">    
                    $72.95</span>
                </li>
```

Therefore my xpath to grab the price is;

```
prices = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@class = "lvprice prc"]')
for price in prices:
    item['price'] = float(price.xpath('span[1]/text()').extract()[0].strip()[1:].replace(',',''))
```

It didn't work for some of the urls, so I looked at the response I got for the ones it didn't work. and the response look like this;

```
<li class="lvprice prc">

        <span  class="bold">
                <b>ZAR</b> 2,656.74</span>
            </li>
```

Any suggestions how to deal with this

Thank you! (Domain is ebay.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are those prices really are in DOM before AJAX is executed?

Maybe prices are being loaded by AJAX call.

Try disabling JS in your browser and see of that HTML is in the page.

By the way, use this XPATH to select element with more that one classes.

```
//*[contains(@class, 'class1') and contains(@class, 'class2')]
```

**EDIT:**

I am 100% sure that eBay is showing Captcha page because of many requests from same IP. Remember that eBay is not BABY website, its a really big company and they are against scraping. They block IPs which scrape them.

I also used to scrape Amazon, eBay and few other big websites, they are really against crawling them.

Do this to see what response looks like when prices is not in your response.

```
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

def parse_details(self, response):
    try:
        Selector(response).xpath('//*[@class = "lvprice prc"]').extract()[0]
    except Exception:
        open_in_browser(response)
```

This will open the scraped page in your OS's default browser.

Comment: I guess so, when I disable javascript and go to ebay.com on my browser it's just an empty page it won't show anything. If i try the link that I was trying to scrape it would show this:                 Please enable JavaScript

Our new search experience requires JavaScript to be enabled. Please enable JavaScript on your browser, then try again. --- Although I can still do right click and inspect and it would show the same thing: <li class="lvprice prc">

            <span  class="bold">    
                    $72.95</span>
                </li>

Comment: Also sometimes I can get it from the same page and sometimes I can't from the same exact page... I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: @CanGokalp eBay maybe sending captcha to your response. Please see the edits in my answer.

Comment: I wasn't getting captcha but your code helped me debug and find out the problem =) thank you!. I was using proxy service and the problem was its international proxy and ebay changes currency depending on where the request was made. that's why it was showing ZAR, south african currency. I'm trying to figure out how to fix this now